# Android setOnClickListener change intent putExtra

Tags: android

I have the following code below (which works) inside onCreate:

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            try{
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebView.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("choice", buttonclick_url); 
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);    
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
```

buttonclick_url contains the url to load on the WebView class. I would like this url to be changeable depending on certain things that happen. However, I am unable to declare anything inside onClick without setting them as 'final' which then cannot be changed since all of these get initialized and set during onCreate method.

Is there any way to make the buttonclick_url changeable so that I can load any url I want even after the button has been initialized in onCreate?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not make a function which would return the URL ?

Comment: If you can then just make it global variable and your problem will be reolved.

Comment: hmm that sounds like an ingenious idea. I will test it out and return with my findings! thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use a **global variable** but I think it's better to use a method, so your final code will look like something to the similar snippet:

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            try{
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebView.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("choice", getUrlForMyButton(view.getTag())); 
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);    
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });


public string getUrlForMyButton(string s)
{
   //TODO
}
```

Obviously if you are using that method for only that button you don't need to pass an argument containing the `tag`.

Here's the example with a global variabile

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private string MyUrl;


  mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        try{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebView.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("choice", MyUrl); 
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);    
        } catch (Exception e) {}
       }
  });

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: best answer as it incorporates function calling + global variable in code

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    mybutton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try{
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebView.class);
        //do anything with url
        myIntent.putExtra("choice", buttonclick_url);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

}